# What does "java -version 2>&1 |awk 'NR==1{ gsub(/"/,""); print $3 }'" do?

Tags: bash, awk

everyone. I've been trying to understand this line of a script but I just really can't. I'm new at bash scripting so it is kind of pretty difficult :(

```
java -version 2>&1 |awk 'NR==1{ gsub(/"/,""); print $3 }'
```

I would appreaciate it a lot

Comment: You should tell us _what_ in this line you do not understand. Otherwise you ask us to explain the whole logic of unixoid systems, which probably no one will do...

Comment: A question's title needs to be specific to the question. If that means including the line in the title, do that.

Comment: ...that said, `awk` is not part of bash; it's a separate programming language with its own syntax and rules. If your question is about the awk script, you should be tagging this `awk`, not `bash`.

Comment: It's clearly a processing of the "version" string given out by java. Output is captured on both stdin and stderr and piped to the "awk" processor which then prints the 3rd element of (I don't know what).

Comment: @DavidTonhofer, ...of the first line (`NR==1`), after splitting on literal double-quotes (`"`). Silly to do it that way -- no reason one couldn't do all the processing in native bash without spinning up any external processes at all.

Comment: By the way -- a good place to start with this kind of question is https://explainshell.com/. It won't parse `awk`, but at least will explain the rest of the content, so the question could be narrowed to what the OP still doesn't understand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, this is unlikely to be run a million times in a row. Myself, I like to quickly pipe into a perl one-liner as needed. It's not like we are in the early 90's anymore (running Unix on Motorola 68K? Yes we did!)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer, sure, it's unlikely to be run a bunch of times in a row, but it's also less readable than using a simple regex or `read` command with `IFS` set, unless someone knows not only bash but also awk; it's thus requiring more knowledge to parse and explain.

Answer (score 5):

- `java -version 2>&1` runs `java` with the argument `-version`. As this implies, it tells the Java runtime to print its version. `2>&1` is a redirection that makes the `stderr` file descriptor (conventionally used for logging and human-readable text) write to the same destination as `stdout` (conventionally used for machine-parsed output), such that human-readable text (such as our version number!) goes through the pipeline.
- The pipe character, `|`, connects the output of the command on the left to the input of the command on the right.
- `awk 'NR==1{ gsub(/"/,""); print $3 }'` invokes the text-processing program `awk`, with a program used to parse the output which does the following:

  - `NR == 1` indicates that the following code only runs for the first line of input
  - `gsub(/"/, "")` removes literal double quotes from the input.
  - `print $3` prints the third field of the line of input given.

---

Personally, I would write this as follows:

```
# uses only bash builtins; first two _s are placeholders for the words we don't care about
IFS=' "' read -r _ _ version < <(java -version 2>&1)
```

...following which, `echo "$version"` will emit your Java release.

---

Even better, with less fragility:

```
#!/bin/bash
java_version_re='^java version "([^"]+)"'
if [[ $(java -version 2>&1) =~ $java_version_re ]]; then
  version=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  echo "Detected java version as $version" >&2
else
  echo "Could not detect java version" >&2
fi
```

This version can detect when the output *isn't* a correct Java version string, which the original could not.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest method is to break down the parts:

*java -version 2>&1* give you the java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b16)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b16, mixed mode)
```

*awk 'NR==1'* gives you the first line:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
```

*print $3* gives you the third word:

```
"1.8.0_111"
```

and finally *gsub(/"/,"")* strips the " charachter:

```
1.8.0_111
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk parses the 1st line of input, then removes double quotes and prints the 3rd field.

Awk is a programming language on his own, you will not understand it just by pretending it is bash

Comment: The `/`s delimit regexes in awk, they're not part of the actual matched or replaced text.